# Visual Paradigm for UML - Allow duplicate names

Tags: erd, visual-paradigm

Is there a way how to allow duplicate names in ERD diagrams in Visual Paradigm for UML? What I am trying to do is to document database changes. I want to have every database version in separate diagram. Changes to database are incremental so there are many objects with the same name in different diagrams. Now I am constrained to use postfixes. So first diagram contains table named "METER". Second diagram contains table named "METER2" which is not a real name of database object. In fact "METER2" table doesnt exist, real name is "METER".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different Models. Go to "Model Explorer", create a new model and then you can use the same entity names in different ERD diagrams.